# Css reset options for Html5 css layout and jQuery UI

Tags: html, css, css3pie

I am using default ASP.NET MVC 3.0 Html5 css layout(comes witch tools updates) and I am also using jquery ui a lot.

In all modern browsers all looking pretty similar.
But when i start to look at old IE versions i was very upset, website layout just breaks there. I have `<ul>`menu `inline-block` but in old ie it is not supported so i find out one fix [IE7 does not understand display: inline-block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544852/ie7-problem-with-display-inline-block):

```
/* For IE 7 */
zoom: 1;
*display: inline;
```

but it still required some work in my case to make it looks the same like in modern browsers.

Also i found the fix how to add support css rounded corners in old IE browsers with CSS3Pie, but it is still required some work around because if element with rounded corners has margins, the CSS3Pie ignored them [CSS3Pie margins sets to zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353757/css3pie-margins-sets-to-zero).

Also i am using html tag `<button>` but in old IE they just sucks. I asked this question before [jQUery ui buttons some issues in IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354647/jquery-ui-buttons-some-issues-in-ie7) and one of replies was to use `Css rest`.

After i googled that i find out there is quite a lot of them:

http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2011/01/03/reset-revisited/

http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/

http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/

...and even more but this ones looks quite popular.

So and my question is which `CSS reset` better to choose in my case?
I am using `ASP.NET MVC 3.0 Html5 css layout` + `jquery-ui`.  Also looking at `ASP.NET MVC 3.0 Html5 css layout` i could say that it has some css reset in it or it is really not css reset or at least may be it is not enough?

p.s

Really internet should ban IE7 because it is breaks nice layouts.

Answer (score 0):

You better be using HTML5Boilerplate which comes with Normalize CSS reset and once you add JQuery UI it will work on top of existing browser capabilities. I have not tested for IE7 or lower but I prefer to tell user that browser is out of date and they need to upgrade to view website or continue and it might reduce their experience as compared to recent browsers. An icon and link to Chrome, Firefox and IE9 has always helped at this stage.

Anyway answer to your question is to use HTML5Boilerplate. Search for Normalize CSS or HTML5Boilerplate and you will see it works pretty much. Combile your search with MVC3 and you will find a whole MVC3 project on Github which you can use as a starting point.

Comment: how you checking for old browser? you checking just versions or html5/css3 capabilities? mmmm and better to have link to modern browser somewhere on top of the page isn't it? Do you know any samples too look at?